# Android: Using Parse to update Object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to create an application which will change the object:status of Class:attendance, from 1 to 0 and vice versa via 2 buttons (start & stop).

The change will then be read by another device to check the attendance. (not impt to the question but might be useful)

I tried to search for tutorials or samples or video but couldn't do it. Can someone help me on this pls?

```
    startAttdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(AttendanceActivity.this, "Attendance taking starts now. Click STOP to end session.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Attendance");

            // Retrieve the object by id
            query.getInBackground("v4nWkoFlmZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {  //retrieve serverID instead of object from parse
                public void done(ParseObject Attendance, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        Attendance.put("Status", 1);
                        Attendance.saveInBackground();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                }

            });
        }
    });

    stopAttdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(AttendanceActivity.this, "Attendance taking ended. Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ParseObject attendance = new ParseObject("Attendance");
            attendance.put("Status", 0);
            attendance.saveInBackground();
            //startActivity(intentAttdResult);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Currently, clicking the 'start' btn will display the toast, but does not update the object on parse at all.
clicking the 'stop' btn will display the toast, and create a new id in 'Attendance' with status undefined.

Comment: why do you have two `done` methods in `GetCallback`?

Comment: I copied from somewhere. 
I'm guessing the second done method is for the ParseObject GetCallBack.

Answer (score 0):

Start code looks fine, it should be updating the Attendance object as long as the ObjectId matches an existing item. Perhaps add a callback to your `saveInBackground()` to confirm that it worked and didn't get any error.

As for your Stop code, I figure you would want to follow the same pattern there of using an objectId to modify an existing row.

Just a note, you don't have to get the object first... you can just modify that single field and save as Parse will do a "patch", i.e. just make your change. So if you new up a ParseObject with the right ID and change the Status and call `saveInBackground()` it'll work just as well and save you that extra query hit.

Comment: It did not update. 

Upon scrutinizing my code. I saw that the method here, " public void done(ParseObject Attendance, ParseException e)" was greyed out. Meaning it was never used. 

I have no idea why that happened. Anyone can enlighten pls?

Comment: Looks like @Lamorak has your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetCallback` is wrong. You have implemente two `done()` methods. Only the empty one gets called since it has the `@Override` notation. This is what the `GetCallback` should look like

```
new GetCallback<ParseObject>() { 
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject Attendance, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Attendance.put("Status", 1);
            Attendance.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
});
```